# java how to get superclass method to modify subclass field

Tags: java, inheritance, field, hidden

I have two classes A and B as below

```
public class A {
    Number x;

    public A (){
        x = 10;
    }

    public void setX(Number x){

        //do a bunch of super complicated and lengthy stuff
        // afterwards set x
        this.x = x;
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    int x;

    public B(){
        super();
    }

    public void setX(int x){
        super.setX(x);
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

and my Main is

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B test = new B();
        test.setX(9);
        System.out.println(test.getX());
    }
}
```

The output is 0. I want it to be 9. I realize that in this trivial example I could just write x = 9 in my method in B, but if it were a more complicated method where I didn't want to rewrite all the code that was already written in my superclass method then how would I make that happen?

EDIT: in subclass B I am purposely calling my int variable x to hide the superclass variable x. Pretend the setX method in the superclass does a ton of other stuff before finally setting x. I want it to set the x of the subclass instead. is this possible? This is a trivialized example. In my actual problem it's much more complicated.

EDIT: actual problem is this. I have a class called `ColorBinaryTree` which is a subclass of `BinaryTree`. the only difference is the `ColorBinaryTree` class has a field for color so I can implement a red-black tree. The BinaryTree class references to parent, left, and right which are all BinaryTree objects. The ColorBinaryTree class has the same references but they are ColorBinaryTree objects instead of BinaryTree objects. I have a bunch of methods which manipulate the tree. One example would be the following

```
public BinaryTree<E> root() {
    if (parent == null) return this;
    else return parent.root();
}
```

In my subclass I need to override this so I can do covariant return type and return a ColorBinaryTree object. But it would be nice if i could call the superclass method inside my subclass method. But it seems that if I call the superclass method it looks at the superclass's parentfield. I want it to look at the subclass's parent field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use generics, you use Java 5. What about overriding the methods with a more specific return type:

```
class BinaryTree<E> {
  public BinaryTree<E> root() {
    if (parent == null) return this;
    else return parent.root();
  }
}

class ColorBinaryTree<E> extends BinaryTree<E> {
  @Override
  public ColorBinaryTree<E> root() {
    return (ColorBinaryTree<E>)super.root();
  }
}
```

Or may use a more sophisticated generic solution:

```
abstract class AbstractBinaryTree<E, T extends AbstractBinaryTree<E,T>> {
  T parent;

  public T root() {
    if (parent == null) return (T)this;
    else return parent.root();
  }
}

class BinaryTree<E> extends AbstractBinaryTree<E, BinaryTree<E>>{
}

class ColorBinaryTree<E> extends AbstractBinaryTree<E, ColorBinaryTree<E> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start off with the fact that the two variables are named `x` - that's a complete coincidence as far as the compiler's concerned. It's not like `B.x` "overrides `A.x`. If you want polymorphic behaviour, you've got to use methods.

Now you could override setX in B:

```
@Override
public void setX(Number x)
{
    this.x = x.intValue();
}
```

You might *also* want to make it call `super.setX()`.

It would help if you could give a more realistic example though - I'd avoid a design like this to start with...

Comment: I thought naming both of them x is how to "hide" a field?

Comment: @jhlu87: Well it effectively hides it *within the code in B*. Frankly it shouldn't usually matter, as usually your fields should be private to start with, so you shouldn't have access to your superclass's fields.

Comment: @jhlu87: Hiding superclass fields is *not* going to help you. Having two variables which contain *effectively* the same data is a bad idea.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, if what you say is true then there is really no point for me to make ColorBinaryTree a subclass of BinaryTree. Still it seems if I do do it this way I can at least take advantage of a methods that do rotations. It seems wrong to have to copy and paste so much code when the only difference is just the addition of one String field.

Comment: You certainly can make `ColorBinaryTree` a subclass of `BinaryTree`. You just have to live with the fact that e.g. `parent` is a reference to a `BinaryTree` and not specifically to a `ColorBinaryTree`. Which is fine, in normal cases, because even if you are writing a `ColorBinaryTree` method that interacts with the node's `parent`, it can normally do so through the `BinaryTree` interface, and rely on polymorphism to do the right thing at runtime.

Comment: ... wait, one `String` field? Surely an enum or even just a boolean would be a better way to represent red/black "colour" for tree nodes?

Comment: @Karl, if I were to add a node to the red black tree then in some cases I would have to change the color of the new nodes ancestors. Is the appropriate way to do this to get the parent through the BinaryTree interface, cast to a ColorBinaryTree, and then modify the color? Also regarding the String, yea i didn't really think about it until later.

Answer (score 0):

You've re-defined x in your child class.  Take the int x declaration out and remove the "super." part of the setX method so it just reads: "this.x = x".

The root of your problem, is you are changing the x defined in class A, then providing the value in class B which was initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You ouput the private int x from the subclass and set the Number variable in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "x" variable from your class B.  Your method getX() is returning that and not the one in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution without an own member (as long as x in A is not private):

```
public class B extends A {

  public void setX(int x){
    super.setX(x);
  }

  public int getX(){
    return x.intValue();
  }
}
```

It is never a good design to have equal named members in a class hierarchy!

Comment: See my edit on the bottom for my more complicated actual problem. I had that originally, but I need the tree references to also be ColorBinaryTree objects. That's why I declared them again. I used the same name in hopes of hiding the references in the superclass so I can take advantage of inherited methods.

Comment: "I need the tree references to also be ColorBinaryTree objects." Why?

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem myself just now, and of course your question too.

One thing you can do - is reinitialise (NOT construct new ones with the same names) the fields `parent`, `left` and `right` in the constructor of your `ColorBinaryTree` class, to be `ColorBinaryTree` objects.

This should be possible if your class is indeed a subclass of `BinaryTree` and these fields aren't private or package-private.

Now, these fields will be `ColorBinaryTree` objects but will still be seen as `BinaryTree` objects because this what they were declared as in the superclass (`BinaryTree`). To overcome this, you can simply cast them into `ColorBinaryTree` objects whenever necessary.